# What's wrong with this randomize function?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I give it 0 and 400 and it returns me sometimes values above 400. That doesn't make sense.

```
- (float)randomValueBetween:(float)low andValue:(float)high {
    return (((float) arc4random() / RAND_MAX) * (high - low)) + low;
}
```

that's actually a snippet I found on the net. Maybe someone can see the bug in there?

Comment: Just to be pedantic, this bug has not much to do with UIKit, iPhone, or (barely) Objective-C ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [manual page for `arc4random`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) indicates that the returned value can be anywhere in the range valid for `u int32` (i.e. `0 to (2**32)-1`). This means you'll want to divide by `0xFFFFFFFF`, instead of `RAND_MAX`, which I would imagine is less (it is library dependant however, so you'll have to check exactly what it is).

Your function should thus become:

```
- (float)randomValueBetween:(float)low andValue:(float)high {
    return (((float) arc4random() / 0xFFFFFFFFu) * (high - low)) + low;
}
```

Comment: I'd use `UINT32_MAX` rather than the explicit value.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like he's really angry `0xffffffffu`!

Answer (score 6):

- `arc4random` returns a pseudo-random value from zero to (2 ^ 32 - 1)
- `RAND_MAX` has a default value of (2 ^ 31 - 1)

So the function is probably multiplying the `(high - low)` range by up to a factor of `2`, for random values in the range `0 - 800`.

Answer (score 3):

On the iPhone, RAND_MAX is 0x7fffffff (2147483647), while arc4random() will return a maximum value of 0x100000000, so (4294967296) / (2147483647) = 2.....
2 * (400-0) + 0 = 800 ! the max value the method can return

Answer (score 0):

A simpler variant would be:

```
- (float)randomValueBetween:(float)low andValue:(float)high {
    return (arc4random() % * (high - low)) + low;
}
```

Since you're already doing a mod operation why not do it directly on the range of interest?

Also, why are you passing in floats (and returning floats) if you only ever pass in round numbers?  Integers are more efficient.

Comment: If the difference between `high` and `low` is floating point then you'd need to call [`fmodf()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/fmodf.3.html)