# CCRandom_0_1() generate the same number

Tags: iphone, ios, random, cocos2d-iphone

i use CCRandom_0_1() to generate a random number, as suggested in the book 'learn-iphone-and-ipad-with-cocos2d'
but it seems the function generates the same number.

```
    int ran1 = ((int) (CCRANDOM_0_1() * 5)) + 1;
    int ran2 = ran1;
    while (ran2 == ran1) {
        ran2 = ((int) (CCRANDOM_0_1() * 5)) + 1;
    }
```

here is the code where i want to generate 2 different integer from 1 to 5. but the console is always

```
2011-05-28 14:57:56.699 LetsSpotIt[2443:707] r1: 4.200939 r1: 1.971915
```

Is there anyway i can seed it according to time(mini second something), or is there any other functions to use?

Please give me example code. I didn't learn c or c++ before. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried arc4random() function? Also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c)

Comment: nope, but i think they are more or less the same. so i assumed i would encounter the same problem for every random functions

Comment: yeah, this function is great. but what if i want to use float or double instead of integer?

Comment: Interesting. I googled it and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131101/whats-wrong-with-this-randomize-function and http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/random-thoughts-rand-vs-arc4random.html

Comment: yeah, worked great for both int and float. don't need to seed at all. cheers.

Comment: (((float) arc4random() / 0xFFFFFFFFu) * (high - low)) + low for random float from 'low' to 'high'; arc4random() % aInt for random int from 0 to aInt - 1;

Answer (score 6):

If you want different values every time you use the code, then you must seed the random generator. The most popular way is to call srandom(time(NULL)) before using CCRANDOM

Comment: you mean add srandom(time(NULL)) line before every CCRandom function or just add once in the app delegate?

Comment: Just once in the delegate or some other place ;) Sorry, should've told you that too...